# Ionic: Splitting an <a> tag window.open url to include data

Tags: javascript, html, url, ionic-framework, window.open

I am trying to split up a URL in my  tag.

Inside one of my templates.html files in Ionic, I am linking externally to Twitter and Facebook.

I am using Cordova InAppBrowser and to cut a long story short, the links for Twitter and Facebook open in the correct apps/system browsers... but I cannot figure out a way to include data of which I can use in a simple  version.

When using:

```
<a class="twitter" onClick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{offer.title}}%20-%20{{offer.business.data.name}}%20-%20via%20@handle','_system','location=yes');return false;"><i>&#xE12f;</i> Twitter</a>
```

It opens correctly, but does not inherit the correct data for {{offer.title}} and {{offer.business.data.name}} - I need a way for it to include this.

When using:

```
<a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{offer.title}}%20-%20{{offer.business.data.name}}%20-%20via%20@handle" target="_system"><i>&#xE12f;</i> Twitter</a>
```

It loads the correct data into the URL, but does not open correctly at all which is more of an issue - there must be a way to do a simple:

```
'url.com/' + {{offer.title}} + '/something'
```

or something?

Comment: you'll need to use `ng-click` and a function in your controller.

Comment: Ahh yes I was having a play with my controllers.js file and I added a $scope to try and take care of this but I didn't know how to refer to this using ng-click="openTwitter()" - it kept saying an error: openTwitter was not defined or something along those lines.

Comment: I used this code which definitely works now to open a link using the ng-click you mentioned, but it errors saying **ReferenceError: offer is not defined**

`$scope.openTwitter = function() {
      window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + offer.title + '%20-%20via%20@handle', "_system");
    }`

Comment: you would either need to pass in the `offer` you want, or if `offer` is a property of `$scope`, use `$scope.offer`.  I don't recommend the second option, since it is less flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed this by using your suggestion and the answer below with the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the most efficient way to handle this in Angular.js would be with ng-click.  Something like the following:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.offer = {
    title: 'someTitle',
    business: {
      data: {
        name: 'some Business'
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.openTwitter = function(offer) {
    window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' +
      offer.title +
      '%20-%20' +
      offer.business.data.name +
      '%20-%20via%20@handle', '_system', 'location=yes');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="openTwitter(offer)" href="">Open Twitter</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tqQWHc0nlp9Rpo85aSbV

Comment: Great! Thank you! I managed to use your code with a few tweaks here and there to make it work both inheriting the correct data from the API/DB and allow it to open correctly in the Twitter app/system browser - thanks!